# Time Complexity Comparison of KMP string search to Boyer-Moore string search

Tags: c++

I am doing a project to compare the time complexity of 2 string search algorithms. 
I lost my previous code due to some issues and so have had to rewrite the majority.
However, this time around, my KMP algorithm seems to be running a lot slower, and I can never actually get it to run faster than my Boyer-Moore no matter what I input.
Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

//set number of characters for lookup table
# define number_chars 256

//type alias for clock
typedef chrono::steady_clock clocktime;



void boyer_moore(string text, string pattern, int textlength, int patlength) {

    //start timer
    clocktime::time_point start = clocktime::now();

    //create vector list of all the locations the pattern was found
    vector<int> indexes;

    //create array for lookup table
    int lookup[number_chars];

    //initially fill every index of lookup table with -1
    for (int i = 0; i < number_chars; i++) {
        lookup[i] = -1;
    }
    //for every character in pattern, set lookup table at index = integer value for character to be the index of the character within the pattern
    for (int i = 0; i < patlength; i++) {
        lookup[(int)pattern[i]] = i;
    }
    //shift variable for keeping track of location in text
    int shift = 0;


    while (shift <= (textlength - patlength)) {
        int j = patlength - 1;

        //works through pattern from end to start checking if characters in text match, stops when j<0 or character in text doesn't match character in pattern
        while (j >= 0 && pattern[j] == text[shift + j]) {
            j--;
        }
        //if pattern found
        if (j < 0) {

            //add location pattern was found to location list
            indexes.push_back(shift);

            //if have not reached end of text
            if (shift + patlength < textlength) {

                //skip over pattern just found so next character in text lines up with last character of pattern
                shift += patlength - lookup[text[shift + patlength]];
            }

            //if pattern occurs at end of text add 1 to shift -> next while loop will fail
            else {
                shift += 1;
            }
        }
        //if pattern not found
        else {

            //checks if current character in text is an ASCII character -> if not it would be negative
            //(was having some issues previously with non-ASCII characters setting my array to out of bounds so added this condition)
            if (lookup[text[shift + j]] > -1) {

                //shifts pattern so unmtaching character in text lines up with last character in pattern
                shift += max(1, j - lookup[text[shift + j]]);
            }

            //if non-ASCII character, then it is not in pattern being searched anyway -> skip to next character
            else {
                shift += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //end timer
    clocktime::time_point end = clocktime::now();

    //calculate time taken
    auto time_taken = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();

    //display index locations of pattern
    cout << "Index locations of '" << pattern << "':" << endl;
    for (int in : indexes) {
        cout << in << ", ";
    }

    //display time taken
    cout << endl << endl << endl << "Boyer-Moore: time taken: " << time_taken << "ms" << endl << endl << endl;
}



void kmp(string text, string pattern, int textlength, int patlength) {

    //start time
    clocktime::time_point start = clocktime::now();

    //create vector list of all the locations the pattern was found
    vector<int> indexes;

    //creates prefix table 
    //had to use vector as compiler was complaining about patlength not being a constant value, even when I set it it const int
    vector<int> table(patlength);

    //keeps track of length of previous longest prefix suffix
    int k = 0;


    //filling in prefix table
    for (int i = 1; i < patlength; i++) {
        while (k > 0 && pattern[k] != pattern[i]) {
            //u
            k = table[k-1];
        }
        if (pattern[k] == pattern[i]) {

            //update longest suffix
            k = k + 1;
        }
        table[i] = k;
    }
    int textindex = 0;
    int patindex = 0;
    while (textindex < textlength) {
        if (pattern[patindex] == text[textindex]) {
            textindex++;
            patindex++;
        }
        if (patindex == patlength) {
            indexes.push_back(textindex-patlength);
            patindex = table[patindex - 1];
        }
        else if (textindex < textlength && pattern[patindex] != text[textindex]){
            if (patindex != 0) {
                patindex = table[patindex - 1];
            }
            else {
                textindex++;
            }
        }
    }

    //end timer
    clocktime::time_point end = clocktime::now();
    auto time_taken = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    cout << "Index locations of '" << pattern << "':" << endl;
    for (int in : indexes) {
        cout << in << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl << endl << "KMP: time taken: " << time_taken << "ms" << endl << endl << endl;
}



//load file method borrowed from lab exercise
string load_file() {
    std::string directory = "";
    string text;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        const string & filename = "dna.txt";
        //https://www.kaggle.com/ashishsinhaiitr/lord-of-the-rings-text/version/1#01%20-%20The%20Fellowship%20Of%20The%20Ring.txt
        ifstream f(directory + filename, std::ios_base::binary);
        if (!f.good()) {
            directory = "../" + directory;
            continue;
        }

        f.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
        const size_t length = f.tellg();

        vector<char> buf(length);
        f.seekg(0);
        f.read(buf.data(), length);
        text.assign(buf.begin(), buf.end());

        return text;
    }
}



void main() {

    //loads text file
    string text = load_file();
    bool end = false;
    while (end == false) {

        //gets pattern from user
        cout << "pattern: ";
        string pattern;
        cin >> pattern;
        int n = text.size();
        int m = pattern.size();

        //call both string search algorithms
        boyer_moore(text, pattern, n, m);
        kmp(text, pattern, n, m);

        //ask user if they want to end the program
        cout << "Close program? (1 = yes, 0 = no): ";
        bool valid = false;

        //checks if user provided valid response -> asks for another if not
        while (valid == false) {
            int userend;
            cin >> userend;
            if ((int)userend == 1) {
                valid = true;
                end = true;
            }
            else if ((int)userend == 0) {
                valid = true;
            }
            else {
                "Please enter a valid number: ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As an example, in my previous results, for the word "the", Boyer-Moore took around 260ms and KMP took around 184ms. Now, Boyer-Moore of course still takes roughly 260ms, however KMP now takes around 330ms.
Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to code review. Your original title could have gotten your question closed. Please try to follow the code review guidelines at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

Without a description of the KMP algorithm I can't begin to check where the code might be going wrong.

### Make Sure to Fix all Warnings

When you are writing and compiling your code you might want to try to get all the warning messages as well as the compiler errors. Currently you have a possible bug in `string load_file()`, the compiler warning message for this is `'load_file': not all control paths return a value`. The `return text;` statement is inside the `for` loop so if the loop exits after 6 iterations the function doesn't return a value. Another possible bug is that since the `return text;` statement is in the `for` loop and it is not nested within an if statement the `for` loop only performs one iteration.

A second problem that my compiler caught is that the declaration of `main()` is incorrect. The function `main()` is supposed to return an integer value to the operating system that indicates the status of the program, therefore the declaration should be:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    ...
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*Note if the program fails [EXIT_FAILURE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status) can be returned from `main()` instead.*

### Avoid `using namespace std`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

### Need More Error Checking of User Input

The code performs error checking in `main()` for if the user wants to continue or not, but the code does not check other inputs such as checking the input here

```
        std::cin >> pattern;
```

What if the user just hits the enter key, or they enter an invalid patter?

### Complexity

The functions `main()`, `void boyer_moore(string text, string pattern, int textlength, int patlength)` and `void kmp(string text, string pattern, int textlength, int patlength)` are too complex (do too much). Each of these functions should be simplified by breaking them up into smaller functions that do exactly one thing. There are several reasons for this, one is that it is easier to write, debug, read and maintain smaller functions. A second reason is that some functions can be reused. When I was learning how to design programs in computer science they taught us to keep breaking problems into smaller and smaller pieces until each piece was easy to solve. A third benefit that might prove useful is that functions can be profiled so that you can see where the program is spending the most amount of time.

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

Some examples of functions that should exist to simplify the program:

Called from main:

```
bool executeAgain()
{
    bool end = false;
    bool valid = false;
    do  {
        int userend;
        cin >> userend;
        if ((int)userend == 1) {
            valid = true;
            end = true;
        }
        else if ((int)userend == 0) {
            valid = true;
        }
        else {
            "Please enter a valid number: ";
        }
    } while (valid == false);

    return end;
}
```

Checking user input on `pattern`.

Starting the timer and stopping the timer. (you might want to look at [DRY code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) for this as well because this code is repeated in multiple places)

In KMP each one of the loops looks complex enough to be it's own function, that is probably true in `boyer_moore` as well. By breaking up KMP you might spot the problem yourself.

### Prefer '\n` Over std::endl

When you are worried about performance it is better to output a new line rather than std::endl. std::endl flushes the output buffer and that means that it is calling a system function. Lines such as

```
    cout << endl << endl << endl << "KMP: time taken: " << time_taken << "ms" << endl << endl << endl;
```

can easily be rewritten as std::cout << "\n\n\nKMP: time taken: << time_taken << "ms\n\n\n"; and it will execute faster.

### Prefer std::array Over C Style Arrays

C++ has a lot of container classes that are very useful, the code already uses `std::vector<TYPE>` but there is also `std::array<TYPE, COUNT>`, the benefits of using this container type is that it works similar to the old C style array, but it also can use iterators to index through the array and you can use a ranged for loop rather than hard coding for loops based on size.

It is also better to use `constexpr` to define symbolic constants rather than `#define` which is a C programming construct rather than a C++ programming construct.